# Find $a$ and $b$ that make the following function differentiable for all values of $x$

Tags: calculus

$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 b+a x & x>-1 \\
 b x^2-3 a x+4 & x\leq -1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

How do I solve this question? I'm stuck and not sure how to start it up. I did the derivative using definition of the derivative but not sure what to do afterwards.

Comment: If the function is differentiable, then it is also continuous. Use this to get one condition, and then equate the left and right hand derivatives of $f$ at the point $x = -1$ to get another condition relating $a,b$. These should be enough to figure out $a,b$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the function must be continuous at $x=-1$ 
$$\lim_{x\to -1^-} \, f(x)=\lim_{x\to -1^+} \, f (x)$$
that is
$$b-a=b+3a+4\to a=-1$$

Now the derivative

$$
f'(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 a & x>-1 \\
 2 b x-3 a & x\leq -1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
To be differentiable the derivative must have the same value at $x=-1$ in both directions

for $x<-1$ we have $f'_{-}(-1)=-2b-3a$

and $f'_+(-1)=a$

the two values must be equal so we have

$-2b-3a=a\to b=-2a\to b=2$

The function is differentiable for $a=-1;\;b=2$